# Applying an if Statement in a vb ComboBox

Tags: vba

I am working on Excel sheet that enables a user to save data to Sheet2 from a vbForm in Sheet1.
The Form has a ComboBox with a List (Jan, Feb, March...) but I want when a user selects Jan, the Value Saves as 1, Feb as 2 and so on.
Here is my code..

````
    ```Sub Submit()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

iRow = [Counta(Database!A:A)] + 1

With sh
    .Cells(iRow, 1) = iRow - 1
    .Cells(iRow, 2) = frmForm.txtAdm.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 3) = frmForm.txtIndexno.Value
    .Cells(iRow, 4) = frmForm.cmbMonth.Value = Z

End With

End Sub

Private Sub cmbMonth_Change()

    If cmbMonth.Text = "January" Then
        
        Z = 1
       
    ElseIf cmbMonth.Text = "February" Then
        Z = 2
        
    ElseIf cmbMonth.Text = "March" Then
        Z = 3
        
    End If

End Sub```
````

Comment: Do you want using that `Z` value in another Sub? If yes, did you declare `Z` variable on top of the module where you need to use it? Or on top of a standard module (`Public Z as Long`)...

Comment: No I don't want to use it in another Sub. I have not declared it yet.

Comment: Then, what's wrong with your code? Do you want a simplified way to allocate values from 1 to 12 for each month name? If yes, you should ask for that...

Comment: Still alive? Is my above supposition correct? If yes, please see the code I posted. If not, please explain what you want accomplishing.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a compact code to transform the months name in their number, please use the next way:

```
Private Sub cmbMonth_Change()
   Dim arrMonths, mtch, Z As Long
   
   arrMonths = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", ",")
    mtch = Application.match(cmbMonth.Value, arrMonths, 0)
    If IsNumeric(mtch) Then 
        Z = mtch
    Else
        'Just in case:
        Msgbox "The combo value is not a month name..."
    End If
End Sub
```